# java.io.IOException: No such file or directory (save image)

Tags: android, android-10.0

I upload the photos I selected from the device to ftp. But despite the photo I have chosen from the device, I get the "no such file directory" error. Although I give the application permissions, it does not save it to IMAGE_DIRECTORY that I have chosen in the application. So I get this error. What is the reason why it did not save the file, even though I gave the permissions?

**Error line:** 
            f.createNewFile();

**error code:**

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at com.example.stechome.ui.hesabim.HesabimFragment.saveImage
```

**Fragment**

```
public class asdFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/asdasd";
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA1 = 2;

 private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionACCESS_NETWORK_STATE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
        int permissionWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permissionCAMERA = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int permissionACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (permissionACCESS_NETWORK_STATE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
        }

        if (permissionWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (permissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (permissionCAMERA != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }

        if (permissionACCESS_FINE_LOCATION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

 public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min=100000;
        int maks=1000000;

        int random = r.nextInt((maks-min)+1)+min;


        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "ProfilFoto"+"foto"+random+".jpg");

            f.createNewFile();

            ////
            ///resmi kaydetmek localde kaydetmek için
            /// sadece galeriden görüntü aldıracağımız için kapatıyoruz.
            ///
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            //   Toast.makeText(this, f.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*UploadVideo async = new UploadVideo(f.getAbsolutePath());
            async.execute();*/
            currentimgPath=f.getAbsolutePath();
            dosyaAd=f.getName();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("dosyaAdProfil", dosyaAd);
            System.out.println("dosyaAdProfil" + dosyaAd);
            editor.commit();
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

private void showPictureDialog(){
       /* AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("İşlem Seçiniz");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Galeri'den Seç",
                "Kamera'dan Al" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();

                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();*/
        if (!checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
            return;
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        pictureDialog.setTitle("İşlem Seçiniz");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Galeri'den Seç"};
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }

    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    // String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    //  String pth=contentURI.getPath();

                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    filept=getRealPathFromURI(contentURI);

                    //Toast.makeText(this, filept, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    saveImage(bitmap);




                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "İşlem Başarısız!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA1) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Görüntü Seçildi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

        // can post image
        String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery( contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA1);
        // dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the full error stack

Comment: I updated the subject. @Jagar

Comment: On Android 10 by any chance?

Comment: I do not understand @Andrew

Comment: What Version of Android are you running this on that generates the error? Because there were major file access changes that were made in Android 10 and the type of file access you are doing won't work in Android 10

Comment: yes i am using android 10, how should i edit? Thanks. @Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were major changes on how files can be accessed on Android 10

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

You need to use MediaStore or Storage Access Framework (SAF), details https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared for files outside of your App's private directories.

As you are storing photo then MediaStore would be the way to access pictures
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Though as a quick fix is to temporarily opt out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility but this will only work until Android 11

Some better examples at https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-scoped-storage-8a7e7cafea3

Answer (score 8):

add this to manifest in application tag android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" will ignore on android 11

Comment: ok I need to check once if not then I find a solution and share with you

Answer (score 1):

When i create new file using `mFileNew.createNewFile();` i am getting similor error in android 10 and above.

So, for **android 10** i have used `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in menifest file inside application tag

and for **adroid 11** i have change file path from

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

to

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
```