# Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() in Android 10

Tags: java, android

how can I get

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download
```

in android 10

this method:

```java
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
```

is deprecated is there an alternative way to get or can I use
hardcoded path or is this not recommended?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` ??

Answer (score 1):

See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873203/2373819 you will not by default to be able to use file paths outside of you App's private directories, you need to use Storage Access Framework

The blog https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html has some good details on Download's

With Download manager you don't have to precheck that it exist's just try and download it and then handle the status result that it failed because it already exists.

Comment: thx for response i need access just to check is a file already downloadet from internet or not i cannot find a other solution to do this. when i do it hardcodet it works fine in android Q but i am not shure ist this solution working on all android devices with /storage/emulated/0/Download/myfoto.jpg as exemple

Comment: The question is who/what initiated the download?

Comment: till this point is not initiated. i want to check is a file with filename xyz.jpg or whatever in downloads directoriy if not so then the file can be downloadet from firebase storage through Downloadmanager.

Answer (score 0):

To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps.Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as `Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)`, `MediaStore`, or `Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: thank you for answering but downloads or Images and Videos can still access and it dose work whenn i make this with /storage/emulated/0/Download/mydirecotrie you answer dos not answer my question how cann i access download directory to check is a file like a image.jpg already in or not?

Answer (score 0):

To get permission to manage files we can also use :

```
requestPermission(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

This works because android is now asking to manage external storage.
after allowing it we can use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```